# Odoo production lot grading and displaying of onhand and reserved qtys

Tags: odoo

We are a used electronics wholesaler and have the following situation and would like to know the best way for Odoo to handle it:
A used electronic is taken in, at that time the grade and condition are unknown.  The these two characteristics as well as others will be set through testing and grading operations.  I would like to avoid each item going through several manufacturing processes to achieve the final product attributes, as the number of sku's our company handles is high, and setting up manufacturing rules for each movement is hard if not impossible.

My initial thought was to add the info to the production lots along with a unique serial number to identify each. The trouble I am running into with that approach is, while each item becomes unique through testing and serialization, our customers buy items based on general characteristics. So our sales staff needs to know what items are Onhand and what is reserved within a section criteria. So I need a way to quickly display that we have

- 30 Garmin vivoactive 3's in stock
- 10 untested
- 10 grade A and fully functional units
- 5 Grade B Functional units
- 5 Grade A Nonfunctional units

So that when a customer customer wants 6 fully functional, we are going to send him the Grade B's first, and complete the order with the A's

We need to allocate the inventory in a generic sense not down to the specific items. The intent of allocation is not to assign a specific item to a pick but to stop us from overselling items, we don't always pick items immediately, and want to make sure we have the items available for fulfillment.

We will invoice and track individual items once they are pulled, but our pickers will just go grab the first 6 phones that met the criteria. 5 Bs and 1 A.  They will then scan those items to the pick.

I am hoping for a straight forward Odoo approach to this situation and want to avoid using product variants if possible.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you use categories. You can add the products one by one independently of the "state", and then assign them to some category. Each category will represent a state. After that, you only need to know how many products by category you have. (Maybe you have to do that small module). I hope will be some useful.